# SSIS package running properly but when it came to SQL server agent it showing Successful but Last email task was not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.4000.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
NULL

Comment: I am getting above error when i run that in SQL query analyzer :(

Answer (score 0):

When you create a connection in SSIS and provide password for that it encrypt the password with user key.

So if you create the package then the password will be encrypted with your windows user id. And the password is only decrypt-able if the package is run by your windows account.

But when a package is run through Sql Server Agent Job it uses the windows account that is configured for the Sql Server agent. If this account is different than the account you used to create the package then exception like yours is thrown.

There are couple of ways to avoid this exception.

1. Never save sensitive information in the package. Set "Do not save sensitive" for package protection level. Use configuration or other ways to store the password
2. Run the Sql Server agent with the user account that created the package.

I prefer the first one.

Comment: Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that

Comment: The package was not created by me it was created by another Dev.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server is 64 bit

In SQL Server JOB-->Properties-->Steps--->

1. In the Execution Option Tab -- Check "Use 32 bit runtime"
2. In the Data Sources Tab -- Uncheck the checkboxes of the connection managers if already checked.
3. Schedule the Job and run it.